# Ошибки установки webpack глобально

Tags: node.js, webpack, npm

Установил nodeJS stable версии и npm
NodeJS:

```
v9.8.0
```

NPM:

```
5.6.0
```

В папке проекта делаю npm init, ставлю все настройки по умолчанию, устанавливаю глобально webpack. Вывод в консоль:

[image]
Что за варны, как их можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправлять ничего не нужно, это не ошибка, а всего лишь предупреждение.

Дело в том, что  пакет `fsevents` предназначен только для `macOS` - `Native access to OS X FSEvents`. Вы производите установку на ОС семейства `linux` и поэтому установка этого пакета пропущена.